# How to split specific properties of an entity and save it in separate table and associate using the id?

Tags: jpa

There are 2 entities Document and DocumentData. Now how can I get the field *dataUUID* to contain the field *uuid* which is generated when a byte[] is saved using the DocumentData entity.

```
@Entity(name = "DOCUMENT_DETAILS") 
public class Document extends BaseEntity {

   @OneToOne(targetEntity = DocumentData.class, casacade = Cascade.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "DATA_UUID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "DATA_UUID_ID")
   private String dataUUID;

   @Column(name = "BACK_UP_NAME")
   private String backUpName;
}

@Entity(name = "DOCUMENT_DATA")
public class DocumentData {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
  private String uuid;

  @Column(name = "DATA")
  @Lob
  private byte[] data;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every entity *must* have an `Id` specified. `Document` doesn't. So you need to tell your JPA provider that one side is dependent on the other for it's identity: commonly referred to as `OneToOne` with shared primary key.

To to do you need to make the relationship bi-directional and add the `Id` annotation to the relationship.

It seems to me to make more sense to have DocumentData as the dependent entity:

```
@Entity(name = "DOCUMENT_DETAILS") 
public class Document  {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
   @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
   @Column(name = "DATA_UUID")
   private String dataUUID;

   @Column(name = "BACK_UP_NAME")
   private String backUpName;

   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "document");
   private DocumentData data;
}

@Entity(name = "DOCUMENT_DATA")
public class DocumentData {

  @Id //depends on Document for its ID
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "DATA_UUID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "DATA_UUID_ID")
  private Document document;

  @Column(name = "DATA")
  @Lob
  private byte[] data;
}
```

When saving you need to make sure both sides of the relationship are set correctly:

It makes sense to encapsulate this in the setter in Document:

```
public void setData(DocumentData data){
    this.data = data;
    data.setDocument(this);
}
```

Then:

```
Document doc = new Document();
DocumentData data = new DocumentData();
doc.setData(data);
//save
```

There is another solution where `DocumentData` could be an `Embeddable` rather than an independent entity however I won't go into that.

Comment: Id is inherited from the BaseEntity.

Comment: The answer as given above is how it should be modelled so remove the dependency on `BaseEntity`